# Android CustomListView overlapping other components

Tags: android

In my application I have a header (at the top) and a footer(at the bottom) and a `CustomListView` inside. I have made the HEADER & FOOTER stationary and they won't scroll. But the `ListView` which is placed between them, has some components which are overlapping the FOOTER. I somehow want those components in my `CustomListView` not to overlap the footer. Is there any way this can be done?

The code for my layout is given below-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Title Bar -->

<include
    android:id="@+id/title_bar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    layout="@layout/title_bar" />

<!-- Settings Components list -->

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/custom_items_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/title_bar"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>

<!-- Options Bar -->

<include
    android:id="@+id/options_bar"
    style="@style/btn_options_bar"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    layout="@layout/options_bar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. The problem was, (I don't know why but) I needed to set the `layout_height` and `layout_weight` again after `<include>`

For those who are interested, updated xml is-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Title Bar -->    
    <include
        android:id="@+id/title_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        layout="@layout/title_bar" />

    <!-- Options Bar -->    
    <include
        android:id="@+id/options_bar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        style="@style/btn_options_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        layout="@layout/options_bar" />

    <!-- Settings components' list -->    
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/custom_items_list"
        android:layout_above="@id/options_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title_bar">
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding android:layout_above="@id/options_bar" to the ListView?   To do so you would also have to move the declaration of the footer to be above the ListView in the layout file so that you are not referencing an id that hasn't been declared yet.   But even though the options bar would be listed in the layout before the ListView, it would still get displayed below it because of the options_bar layout_alignParentBottom="true".

Comment: Yeah I tried it. But in this case it does not even show the ListView. Also no errors in Logcat.

I also tried `android:layout:below="@id/custom_item_list"` but no luck.